# Connect IDs based on values in rows

Tags: stata

I am planning to do a network analysis and I need to structure my data in such a way that I can use the *community-contributed* command `nwcommands`.

Below is a sample of the data:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str11 idb long(idd1 idd2 idd3)
"62014"  370490  879271 1112878
"62015"  457013 1112878  370490
"62016"  341863 1366174  533773
"62017"  879271  327069  341596
"62018" 1391443 1366174  879271
end
```

Ultimately, I would like to have a matrix with a value of `1` when an `idb` is connected to another `idb` and `0` if not. There is a connection whenever two `idb`'s share at least one `idd` (this does not have to be within the same `idd` column).

Example output:

```
      62014 62015 62016 62017 62018
62014   1     1     0     1     1
62015   1     1     0     0     0
62016   0     0     1     0     1
62017   1     0     0     1     1
62018   1     0     1     1     1
```

How can I do this in Stata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this in `mata`, Stata's matrix programming language:

```
/* Prepare data */

putmata A = (idd*), replace
```

```
/* Define mata functions */

mata:

function foo2(b, c)
{
  res = 0
  for (i = 1; i <= cols(b); i++) {
      for (j = 1; j <= cols(c); j++) {
          if (b[i] == c[j]) res = 1
      }
  }
  return(res)
}

function foo1(a)
{
  M = J(rows(a), rows(a), 0)
  for (i = 1; i <= rows(a); i++) {
      for (j = 1; j <= rows(a); j++) {
          k = foo2(a[i,.], a[j,.])
          if (k == 1) M[i, j] = 1 
      }
  }
  return(M)
}

end
```

```
/* Execute and get results */

mata: B = foo1(A)

getmata (idb*) = B

list

     +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |   idb      idd1      idd2      idd3   idb1   idb2   idb3   idb4   idb5 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 62014    370490    879271   1112878      1      1      0      1      1 |
  2. | 62015    457013   1112878    370490      1      1      0      0      0 |
  3. | 62016    341863   1366174    533773      0      0      1      0      1 |
  4. | 62017    879271    327069    341596      1      0      0      1      1 |
  5. | 62018   1391443   1366174    879271      1      0      1      1      1 |
     +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```