# Connect IDs based on values in rows, ignoring connection between identical IDs

Tags: stata

This is a follow-up to my previous question: [Connect IDs based on values in rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303516/connect-ids-based-on-values-in-rows).

I would now like to consider the case, where connections between identical `idb`'s should be classified as `0`.

The output is similar to the matrix in my previous post but with diagonal elements equal to `0`:

```
      62014 62015 62016 62017 62018
62014   0     1     0     1     1
62015   1     0     0     0     0
62016   0     0     0     0     1
62017   1     0     0     0     1
62018   1     0     1     1     0
```

How can I do this in Stata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily change the values in the diagonal of a matrix as follows:

```
: B
[symmetric]
       1   2   3   4   5
    +---------------------+
  1 |  1                  |
  2 |  1   1              |
  3 |  0   0   1          |
  4 |  1   0   0   1      |
  5 |  1   0   1   1   1  |
    +---------------------+


: _diag(B, 0)

: B
[symmetric]
       1   2   3   4   5
    +---------------------+
  1 |  0                  |
  2 |  1   0              |
  3 |  0   0   0          |
  4 |  1   0   0   0      |
  5 |  1   0   1   1   0  |
    +---------------------+
```

In the context of your question, you can simply do the following:

```
mata: B = foo1(A)
mata: _diag(B, 0)

getmata (idb*) = B

list

     +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |   idb      idd1      idd2      idd3   idb1   idb2   idb3   idb4   idb5 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 62014    370490    879271   1112878      0      1      0      1      1 |
  2. | 62015    457013   1112878    370490      1      0      0      0      0 |
  3. | 62016    341863   1366174    533773      0      0      0      0      1 |
  4. | 62017    879271    327069    341596      1      0      0      0      1 |
  5. | 62018   1391443   1366174    879271      1      0      1      1      0 |
     +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```